# Excel VBA: Format Control dropdown populating unique values in cells

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu, combobox

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim levelDrop As Shape
Set levelDrop = Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Drown 7").ControlFormat

If levelDrop.ListIndex = 1 Then

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B31:B") = Worksheets("Control_Sheet").Range("I3:I213").RemoveDuplicates

End If

End Sub
```

I dont know what the problem is. I keep getting an error saying

> "The item with the specified name was not found".

The line the error points to is the Set statement. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this is the correct name for your control: `Drop Drown 7`

Normaly they getting named like `Dropdown 7`.

Comment: at with line comes the error? what is your dropdown named?

Comment: As per the code, dropdown is called dropdown 7. The error is at the Set statement

Comment: Then simply use `If Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Drown 7").ControlFormat.ListIndex = 1 Then`

Comment: @Adit2789 Feel free to mark my answer as your solution if it helped you